# Why does removing this first part change the answer? -- (inverse square root, java)

Tags: java, math, return, inverse, square-root

```
public static float sqrt(float x) {
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    int i = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = Float.intBitsToFloat(i);  <----- EDIT: x is modified here (smh)
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x*2;
}

public static float sqrtWITHOUTXHALF(float x) {
    int i = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = Float.intBitsToFloat(i);
    x = x*(1.5f - (x/2)*x*x);    // <---- replaced with parens
    return x*2;
}
```

For example the sqrt(2) for the top is 1.4139, while the second is 1.8855.

Why would replacing the xhalf variable with EITHER (x/2) or (x*0.5f), change the resulting value?

**EDIT:** WOW that was very stupid of me for not seeing that. I'm not going to delete this though, sigh.

Comment: It is not the only modification. xhalf does not get modified by the operation on i, where x/2 does

Comment: It could simply be the order of mathematical operations, at a guess.

Comment: For the simple reason the xhalf in the first method is not equal to x/2 in the second one. The mathematical operations you are performing are very different. It's simple as that.

Comment: x is affected after setting xhalf initially. If you set xhalf AFTER x is set, then it would yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the first one to look like this (to get 1.8855)

```
 public static float sqrt(float x) {
    int i = Float.floatToIntBits(x); //initialize i
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = Float.intBitsToFloat(i); //modify x
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x; //then initialize xhalf 
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x*2;
```

}

It produced 1.8855, so both now produce the same thing. However that is the incorrect answer. So this is the reason why you were getting different results.

**UPDATE:**
If you want the second one to produce the correct result you can store x to a temp variable. Like this

```
public static float sqrtWITHOUTXHALF(float x) {
    float _x = x;
    int i = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = Float.intBitsToFloat(i);
    x = x*(1.5f - (_x/2)*x*x);    // <---- replaced with parens
    return x*2;
```

}

Now the new variable `_x` is un modified and will produce the correct result.

Comment: What's the reason though?

Comment: The reason it produces the incorrect result? Or the reason why I did this?

Comment: The reason why moving the line makes a difference. EDIT: forget it. I see it. x is altered after setting xhalf initially :)

Comment: x gets modified by inBitsToFloat before it performs the operation.               inBitsToFloat returns a new value for x. In the original question he stored 0.5f*x in xhalf. Then used xHalf in his output so the original, unmodified value was used to calculate the answer **didn't see you replied till after I finished typing

Comment: @sbowde4 isn't any reason to do the edited version, the reason I chopped out the line was just for cleanliness. edited version still creates another variable, with the same overhead.

Comment: @Mitch Weaver I was just trying to answer your question with a visual representation. I like it when people do that for me, so I do it for others.